# CanvasChart: Cannot draw 2 charts in one page side by side

Tags: javascript, html, canvasjs

I want to draw 2 canvas Charts side by side.

For this, I took table row and drawing each of them in one column.
But only 1 chart is drawn.

However, When I draw them one after another, I can see both the charts.
What's wrong here??

P.S:This code is not from my application, but the situation is similar

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <!--        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="canvasjs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
      <script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>



         window.onload = function () {
            function1();
            function2();
         }
          function function1()
          {
             var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1",
                    {
                       title: {
                          text: "Top Oil Reserves"
                       },
                       animationEnabled: true,
                       axisY: {
                          title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
                       },
                       legend: {
                          verticalAlign: "bottom",
                          horizontalAlign: "center"
                       },
                       theme: "theme2",
                       data: [
                          {
                             type: "column",
                             showInLegend: true,
                             legendMarkerColor: "grey",
                             legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
                             dataPoints: [
                                {y: 297571, label: "Venezuela"},
                                {y: 267017, label: "Saudi"},
                                {y: 175200, label: "Canada"},
                                {y: 154580, label: "Iran"},
                                {y: 116000, label: "Russia"},
                                {y: 97800, label: "UAE"},
                                {y: 20682, label: "US"},
                                {y: 20350, label: "China"}
                             ]
                          }
                       ]
                    });

            chart.render();
         }
         function function2()
          {

               var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                    {
                       theme: "theme3",
                       animationEnabled: true,
                       title: {
                          text: "Crude Oil Reserves Vs Production, 2011",
                          fontSize: 30
                       },
                       toolTip: {
                          shared: true
                       },
                       axisY: {
                          title: "billion of barrels"
                       },
                       axisY2: {
                          title: "million barrels/day"
                       },
                       data: [
                          {
                             type: "column",
                             name: "Proven Oil Reserves (bn)",
                             legendText: "Proven Oil Reserves",
                             showInLegend: true,
                             dataPoints: [
                                {label: "Saudi", y: 262},
                                {label: "Venezuela", y: 211},
                                {label: "Canada", y: 175},
                                {label: "Iran", y: 137},
                                {label: "Iraq", y: 115},
                                {label: "Kuwait", y: 104},
                                {label: "UAE", y: 97.8},
                                {label: "Russia", y: 60},
                                {label: "US", y: 23.3},
                                {label: "China", y: 20.4}


                             ]
                          },
                          {
                             type: "column",
                             name: "Oil Production (million/day)",
                             legendText: "Oil Production",
                             axisYType: "secondary",
                             showInLegend: true,
                             dataPoints: [
                                {label: "Saudi", y: 11.15},
                                {label: "Venezuela", y: 2.5},
                                {label: "Canada", y: 3.6},
                                {label: "Iran", y: 4.2},
                                {label: "Iraq", y: 2.6},
                                {label: "Kuwait", y: 2.7},
                                {label: "UAE", y: 3.1},
                                {label: "Russia", y: 10.23},
                                {label: "US", y: 10.3},
                                {label: "China", y: 4.3}


                             ]
                          }

                       ],
                       legend: {
                          cursor: "pointer",
                          itemclick: function (e) {
                             if (typeof (e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                             }
                             else {
                                e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                             }
                             chart.render();
                          }
                       },
                    });

            chart1.render();


         }

      </script>
      <!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>-->
   </head>
   <body>
      <table><tr><td>
      <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 300px; width: 50%;">
      </div>
            <td>
      <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 50%;">

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of `width: 50%`, try `width:50vw`

Answer (score 2):

Anil,

Using bootstrap you can do it as follows:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <!--        <script src="jquery-1.11.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="canvasjs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
  <script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      function1();
      function2();
    }

    function function1() {
      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer1", {
        title: {
          text: "Top Oil Reserves"
        },
        animationEnabled: true,
        axisY: {
          title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
        },
        legend: {
          verticalAlign: "bottom",
          horizontalAlign: "center"
        },
        theme: "theme2",
        data: [{
          type: "column",
          showInLegend: true,
          legendMarkerColor: "grey",
          legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
          dataPoints: [{
            y: 297571,
            label: "Venezuela"
          }, {
            y: 267017,
            label: "Saudi"
          }, {
            y: 175200,
            label: "Canada"
          }, {
            y: 154580,
            label: "Iran"
          }, {
            y: 116000,
            label: "Russia"
          }, {
            y: 97800,
            label: "UAE"
          }, {
            y: 20682,
            label: "US"
          }, {
            y: 20350,
            label: "China"
          }]
        }]
      });

      chart.render();
    }

    function function2() {

      var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        theme: "theme3",
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
          text: "Crude Oil Reserves Vs Production, 2011",
          fontSize: 30
        },
        toolTip: {
          shared: true
        },
        axisY: {
          title: "billion of barrels"
        },
        axisY2: {
          title: "million barrels/day"
        },
        data: [{
            type: "column",
            name: "Proven Oil Reserves (bn)",
            legendText: "Proven Oil Reserves",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [{
                label: "Saudi",
                y: 262
              }, {
                label: "Venezuela",
                y: 211
              }, {
                label: "Canada",
                y: 175
              }, {
                label: "Iran",
                y: 137
              }, {
                label: "Iraq",
                y: 115
              }, {
                label: "Kuwait",
                y: 104
              }, {
                label: "UAE",
                y: 97.8
              }, {
                label: "Russia",
                y: 60
              }, {
                label: "US",
                y: 23.3
              }, {
                label: "China",
                y: 20.4
              }


            ]
          }, {
            type: "column",
            name: "Oil Production (million/day)",
            legendText: "Oil Production",
            axisYType: "secondary",
            showInLegend: true,
            dataPoints: [{
                label: "Saudi",
                y: 11.15
              }, {
                label: "Venezuela",
                y: 2.5
              }, {
                label: "Canada",
                y: 3.6
              }, {
                label: "Iran",
                y: 4.2
              }, {
                label: "Iraq",
                y: 2.6
              }, {
                label: "Kuwait",
                y: 2.7
              }, {
                label: "UAE",
                y: 3.1
              }, {
                label: "Russia",
                y: 10.23
              }, {
                label: "US",
                y: 10.3
              }, {
                label: "China",
                y: 4.3
              }


            ]
          }

        ],
        legend: {
          cursor: "pointer",
          itemclick: function(e) {
            if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
              e.dataSeries.visible = false;
            } else {
              e.dataSeries.visible = true;
            }
            chart.render();
          }
        },
      });

      chart1.render();


    }
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="chartContainer1" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 200px; width: 100%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Added bootstrap css link and changed code in the body...I hope this helps you..